# Unmarshalling jaxb fail on sub-elements (QName)

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am writting an unmarshaller and I am fighting hard with jaxb to have a working solution.

I wanna unmarshall a MessageDescription generated from .wsdl files. The java class from the wsdl file is :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MessageDescription", propOrder = {
    "source",
    "key",
    "data",
    "extension"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    org.onvif.ver10.schema.ConfigDescription.Messages.class
})
public class MessageDescription {

    @XmlElement(name = "Source")
    protected ItemListDescription source;
    @XmlElement(name = "Key")
    protected ItemListDescription key;
    @XmlElement(name = "Data")
    protected ItemListDescription data;
    @XmlElement(name = "Extension")
    protected MessageDescriptionExtension extension;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "IsProperty")
    protected Boolean isProperty;
    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, String>();
   // Ommited...
```

As there is no @XmlRootElement, I have extends the class with a wrapper and add the annotation myself

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement (name = "MessageDescription", namespace = "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema")
public class MessageDescriptionXmlWrapper extends MessageDescription {
}
```

And I use my "wrapper" MessageDescription class to unmarshall

```
private static MessageDescription parseMessageDescription(final Node messageDescriptionNode) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MessageDescriptionXmlWrapper.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    MessageDescription unmarshal = (MessageDescription) unmarshaller.unmarshal(messageDescriptionNode);
    return unmarshal;
}
```

The unmarshalling process is working, but one sub-sub-sub item is always set to null. I don't know where to look to fix this unmarshalling error.

The attribute who is null is the "type" who is a QName.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
public static class SimpleItemDescription {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Name", required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Type", required = true)
    protected QName type;
```

I suspect that the QName cannot be deserialized because it's not a XML element :

-> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html

And the original .xsd description of the SimpleItemDescription [full file](https://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema/onvif.xsd?189db0&189db0)

```
        <xs:element name="SimpleItemDescription" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Description of a simple item. The type must be of cathegory simpleType (xs:string, xs:integer, xs:float, ...).</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Item name. Must be unique within a list.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:attribute>
                <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:QName" use="required"/>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a package-info.java file

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package your.package.name;
```

into the same folder where MessageDescriptionXmlWrapper is

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunally this doesn't change anything. The Qname object is still null

Comment: I had a similar issue using jaxb-api and, in addition to define package-info.java, removed namespace from XmlRootElement annotation. 

@XmlRootElement (name = "MessageDescription")
public class MessageDescriptionXmlWrapper extends MessageDescription {
}

Comment: import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement (name = "MessageDescription", namespace = "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema")
public class MessageDescriptionXmlWrapper extends MessageDescription {                public MessageDescriptionXmlWrapper(){ super(); } // don't forgot constructors
}

Comment: Still doesn't work, I have found a workaround, and replace xs:qname in the wsdl source file by xs:string. But I hope to found a better solution

Comment: Please try this boilerplate:  https://github.com/gdeignacio/onvif-utils. There are tests in XmlManagerTest.java

Comment: I have try your project, and the QName is still null (the problem is on the unmarshalling). I have found a very ugly workaround and replace the type QName by String in the source wsdl. This is not nice but it's work fine for my purpose.